# How to get value out of the php function (MySQL query)

Tags: php, mysql, function, return

```
    function data1 ($d_year, $d_short, $d_name)
    {
$row=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM database WHERE country='$d_short' AND year='$d_year'")); 
echo"<b>$d_name ".$one=$row['sum']." EUR</b><div id='accitem'>".$row['paste']."</div>"; 
return $one;
    };
```

I have multiple rows and each time there is different value of $one.

```
data1 ("1", "uk", "United Kingdom"); $c_nat=$c_nat+$one;    
data1 ("1", "us", "United States"); $c_nat=$c_nat+$one;
echo $c_nat;
```

In the end off all rows I would like to summarize all of them. Please advise and help ;)

Comment: You're trying to mix too many commands into one line. Define `$one` in a separate line and I bet you get a consistant result.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be as following:

```
$c_nat = 0; //this need to define first
$one = data1 ("1", "uk", "United Kingdom"); 
$c_nat=$c_nat+$one;    
$one = data1 ("1", "us", "United States"); 
$c_nat=$c_nat+$one;
echo $c_nat;
```

As the function is returning some value so you need to store that in a variable to use that.

Answer (score 0):

```
function data1 ($d_year, $d_short, $d_name)
 {
  $one = array();
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM database WHERE country='$d_short' AND year='$d_year'");       
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
    $one[]=$row['sum'];
    echo"<b>$d_name ".$row['sum']." EUR</b><div id='accitem'>".$row['paste']."</div>"; 
}
return $one;
 }
```